# How to convert string numbers to list?

Tags: python

I have a string of numbers like this

```
i = '584,569.2,11515,632'
```

want to convert it to list of number like this.

```
[584,569.2,11515,632]
```

Comment: `list(map(float,i.split(',)))` ?

Comment: `[float(n) for n in i.split(',')]` should do the trick.

Comment: Great! good luck with it, ask a question with what you've tried and researched if you get stuck

Comment: `[int(x) if x.is_integer() else x for x in map(float, i.split(','))] ` if `int` vs `float` dtypes are important

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
i = '584,569.2,11515,632'
numbers = list(map(float, i.split(',')))
print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
[584.0, 569.2, 11515.0, 632.0]
```

Also, as Chris A [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379278/how-to-convert-string-numbers-to-list/56379306#comment99358921_56379278), if the distinction between `int` and `float` is important, you can use [`is_integer()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/is_integer.html):

```
numbers = [int(x) if x.is_integer() else x for x in map(float, i.split(','))]
```

Output:

```
[584, 569.2, 11515, 632]
```